# SQL Count Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I want to get the average amount of unique shops that clients do the shopping in.

My table is called TRANSACTIONS and has the following columns:

- CLIENT NUMBER
- RETAILER
- DATA
- TRANSACTION VALUE

I have this right now but I don't know how to proceed, I need to do R/C My query now:

```
SELECT
  count(distinct CLIENT NUMBER) As C, 
  count(distinct RETAILER) As R 
FROM TRANSACTIONS
group by CLIENT NUMBER
```

Comment: On a side note: Is there really a blank in the column name `CLIENT NUMBER`? You should avoid such names. If there is a blank, you must quote the column name wherever you use it. In SQL Server you do this with brackets (`[CLIENT NUMBER]`, instead of standard SQL double quotes `"CLIENT NUMBER"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two steps:

1. Get the number of unique shops per client.
2. Get the average of that number.

The query:

```
select avg(number_of_shops)
from
(
  select client_number, count(distinct retailer) as number_of_shops
  from transactions
  group by client_number
) clients_with_shop_count;
```

Comment: Side note to OP: probably necessary to use `avg(number_of_shops * 1.0)` to get a decimal average, depending on requirements

Comment: @Charlieface: Thank you for pointing this out. I always forget that SQL Server applies primary school division on integers. I wonder how many software errors this may already have caused worldwide.

Comment: It's not primary school division, it's called static typing: dividing two integers returns an integer, and dividing two decimals returns a decimal. Most good languages work that way, such as C#, C++, Java and many others.